# Scroll not working in table view with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, scroll

I am building a chat application using `UITableView` in Swift 4 programatically . This table view have dynamic cell height. So when I am insert a new row to table view and call

```
self.m_ChatTable.scrollToRow(at: lastIndex, at: .top, animated: true)
```

not working properly. For example when I am inserting two new rows to table view the 1st row become visible after inserting the 2nd row and 2nd row become visible after inserting 3rd row . The scrolling height in tableView not correct.

Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    m_ChatTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    m_ChatTable.separatorStyle = .none
    m_ChatTable.delegate = self
    m_ChatTable.dataSource = self

    m_MainScrollView.addSubview(m_ChatTable)

    m_ChatTable.reloadData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        let msg:Message = m_MessageList[indexPath.row] as Message
        return msg.height + 10


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50 // for example
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let msg = m_MessageList[indexPath.row]
        if (0 != msg.height)
        {
            return msg.height + 10
        }
        else
        {
           return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let height = cell.frame.height
        m_MessageList[indexPath.row].height = height
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.m_MessageList.count
    }
```

Comment: V.Nair please define not working properly?

Comment: There are a number of issues with this code: 1) if you table has `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for row height, don't implement the delegate method.  2) estimatedHeightForRowAt should not be actually calculating the row height - it should be a fixed value like `50`. 3) you shouldn't need to cache the heights in the m_MessageList

Comment: Nobody knows what 'm_MessageList' is.

Comment: m_MessageList the array for storing messages

Comment: not working properly means ,I am calling scrollToRow after inserting row to tableView ,but the new row not become visible to table view.